# Continue import from SVN to Git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm trying to write a script that migrates every SVN revision, old and new, to a git repository. I've initialized a Git repo with `git init` and fetched all reversions with `git svn fetch` from the SVN repo.

I'm currently stuck at a point where I try to import new revisions from the repo by using the fetch command. The result of re-execution of `git svn fetch` show that new revisions were imported, but a `git push origin master` told me that the remote Git repository is up to date and the new revisions would not be exported.

Does anyone have an idea what I did wrong or what I have misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a "pull" or "merge". " fetch" does not update your working tree, so there is nothing to "push".

[What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Comment: Ah! You lead me to the right path, i guess :). With an additional search i found the right solution in [this stack overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7195331/1035445).