# TortoiseGit cloned SVN repository - pull new changes

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, tortoisegit

I cloned an SVN repository using TortoiseGit (it uses git-svn internally).

The change happened perfectly.

However, I would like to pull the new commits that the colleagues made.
I tried `SVN Fetch` and it lists and changed files, but does not seem to add them to the log.

How do I pull the new changes?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do a `rebase` (or `merge`). See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7195331/3883957

Comment: "SVN rebase" in the screenshot seems to be your new best friend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN rebase was the solution to the question. As proposed by @fboule and @yishaiz in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **`All Branches`** checkbox of `Log Message - TortoiseGit` dialog. See:

[image]